# Angular Routing - redirectTo child route without path

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I try to set a Child Route as default route that loads when i just enter the site address.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: ''},
    {
        path: '', component: FrameDefaultComponent,
        children: [
            {path: '', component: SiteCalculatorComponent}
        ]
    },
];
```

But this dont work... When i give the `SiteCalculatorComponent` any route like calc and redirect from level 1 to `'calc'` then it works. I know... But the point is that i want to load it "without" any path ;)

Is this possible? If yes how?

Answer (score 2):

I have one router like this:

```html
const firstRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'parent-url',
        children: secondRoutes
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And second one like this:

```html
export const secondRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'child-route',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'child-route',
        component: ChildComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

My ChildComponent can be called with  /child-route or /parent-url/child-route.
I want to disable calling my function with both routs, so to set able to call it only with /parent-url/child-route.

I dont know how to check if there is /parent-url and if it is not there to disable calling ChildComponent without that /parent-url . in whole url?

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

```
{
    path: '', component: FrameDefaultComponent,
    children: [
        {path: '', component: SiteCalculatorComponent}
    ]
},
```